# Can´t center the p element when it has a background-color with a set width

Tags: css

I´m having trouble automatically centering the p element without the use of margin-left. The body element is center aligned but since there is a background color on the p element it doesn´t work on it...

```css
    p {
      background-color: dimGray;
      width:250px;
      margin-left: 630px;
      
    }
    
    h3 {
      margin: 20px;
    }
    
    h1 {
      margin-top: 30px
    }
    
    a {
      color: red;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Netflix</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/nusBlyscc3HZ_yW7ZSTS3E-Ci8ZZv_ALi1K1eWse3rlX2emUBz_tW0XbCMh9yp_pAnOLN24Ct2OWoBNvH629ziJr9EK_Q3PCB73IwAughUCGA4nZhjN1NvkAIVOq4LGIlw">
    
      <h1>See what´s next</h1>
      <h3>Watch anywhere, but mostly from home</h3>
      <a href="https://mimo.app/r/homeflix.html">Try 30 Days Free</a>
      <p>Watch TV shows and movies</p>
      
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It´s the grey box I have trouble with centering automatically. I can´t seem to find a way to do it.

[image: It´s the grey box I´m having trouble with centering]

Comment: insert your html

Comment: Done now :D Please get back if you know how to solve this :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you gave the "p" a specific width, now you can give it

```
p{
   /* your current style */
   margin:auto;
}
```

Elements with "display:block" property like headers and paragraphs and others, can be centered if you add margin:auto to them after you give them a specific width, without a fixed width, they will take the whole page width

Comment: Thank you. It worked great but the grey box is very close to the text now. How can I change that?

Comment: You give it padding, or you mean the text on top of it?

Comment: Thank you very much my friend :)

Answer (score 0):

to achieve the desired result, you need to add `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` and remove `margin-left: 630px;` in `p` tag.

```css
p {
      background-color: dimGray;
      width:250px;
      /*margin-left: 630px;*/
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      
    }
    
    h3 {
      margin: 20px;
    }
    
    h1 {
      margin-top: 30px
    }
    
    a {
      color: red;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Netflix</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/nusBlyscc3HZ_yW7ZSTS3E-Ci8ZZv_ALi1K1eWse3rlX2emUBz_tW0XbCMh9yp_pAnOLN24Ct2OWoBNvH629ziJr9EK_Q3PCB73IwAughUCGA4nZhjN1NvkAIVOq4LGIlw">
    
      <h1>See what´s next</h1>
      <h3>Watch anywhere, but mostly from home</h3>
      <a href="https://mimo.app/r/homeflix.html">Try 30 Days Free</a>
      <p>Watch TV shows and movies</p>
      
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at flexbox for aligning elements.
You can find some information on it [on the Mozilla Developer Site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

You can get used to using it very quickly and avoids a lot of "messy" styling.